# Chrome extension AJAX/XHR request handling

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Couple questions about the implementation of the XHR request:

I am trying to make a form in popup.html that allows for the filling of a box with text (in popup.html) and submits that to a remote website using get and replaces the contents of the box with the return of the php (json).

Heres the code so far:

Any idea why when I click submit nothing happens?

Also the manifest permissions:

```
  "permissions": [

"https://*/",

"https://*/*"

]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forms don't need permissions at all to do a cross domain post (in theory).  That being said, the popup.html never reloads in a browser action (or page action) when a form is submitted.

An easy thing to do is to capture onsubmit on the form and simply do an XMLHttpRequest attaching the form as per the [Mozilla MDC site](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Retrieving_a_FormData_object_from_an.c2.a0HTML.c2.a0form).

Which in summary is (copied from mozilla):

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("myFormElement");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "submitform.php");
xhr.send(new FormData(formElement));
```